# Converting a proc to a block using ampersand operator does not work after the closing parenthesis

Tags: ruby

It looks like converting a proc to a block using the ampersand operator `&` does not always work in Ruby:

```rb
require 'fileutils'

hi  = proc do puts "Hi!"  end
hey = proc do puts "Hey!" end

def m
  yield
end

m &hi  # prints "Hi!"

FileUtils::cd(FileUtils::pwd) &hey  # does not print anything
```

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should passou blocks with ampersand as an argument like

```
FileUtils::cd(FileUtils::pwd, &hi)
```

Comment: Oh, i have never payed attention.  So, the difference was that in `m` the block was the only argument.

Comment: I guess in `f(x) &p`, `&` is interpreted as a binary operator.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use call here as you do it in block

```
FileUtils::cd(FileUtils::pwd) &hey.call
```

Proc objects is just an unnamed functions, to run a code inside of it you should use .[call](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Proc.html#method-i-call), thats why simply invoking `hey` do nothing in your case

Comment: This works, but it looks very strange to me! Could you explain by any chance what it the meaning of `call` here?

Comment: I have updated an answer. `m &hi` works because `yield` statement is calling a block in this case.

Comment: what's difference between `m` and `cd`?

Comment: I think I have figured out why `FileUtils::cd(FileUtils::pwd) &hey.call` works.  It must be the same as `nothing = hey.call; FileUtils::cd(FileUtils::pwd) &nothing`.  This does not explain why `FileUtils::cd(FileUtils::pwd) &hey` does not work as expected by me.